# The following Code throws exception while opening the file

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(ImagePath);
```

Here Image Path is a string.

> *An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code*
>
> *WinRT information: Cannot access the specified file or folder (폰ጼ¿). The item is not in a location that the application has access to
>   (including application data folders, folders that are accessible via
>   capabilities, and persisted items in the StorageApplicationPermissions
>   lists). Verify that the file is not marked with system or hidden file
>   attributes.*

Comment: The exception seems reasonably clear to me - what isn't clear is what your question is. Does that path look like one which actually exists on your machine? If so, have you checked the permissions and attributes, as the exception says to?

Comment: The path exists in the machine .Lets say the the ImagePath is C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\image.Jpg

Comment: can you post the value of `ImagePath` when the exception occurs?

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda: Well that's certainly not the image path specified in the exception. Look at *that* path - does that exist on your machine? Possibly the problem is how you're obtaining `ImagePath`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: No i can even get the ImagePath printed on the app

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... Please clarify - and look at the value in the exception, which looks odd.

Comment: Related question, but no accepted answer there: [An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753843/an-exception-of-type-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-d)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error tells you everything you need to know. From the error:

> The item is not in a location that the application has access to (including application data folders, folders that are accessible via capabilities, and persisted items in the StorageApplicationPermissions lists)

From your description:

> The path exists in the machine. Lets say the ImagePath is C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\image.Jpg

Your app doesn't have access to that folder. You can find out more in the MSDN article on [File access permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh967755.aspx)